# Relación 1 a 1 en entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

estoy teniendo un problema con una relación 1 a 1, es mas o menos asi
Un Auto tiene un Conductor, en este caso en el modelo tengo

```
public  class Auto {
int IdAuto
string Modelo
int idConductor
Conductor Conductor
}
```

Ahora, hasta ahi esta todo bien, ahora lo que sucede es que ese conductor tiene un usuario y contraseña y tengo que hacerle un login, y cuando hago el login y y me traigo el Conductor, quiero saber que auto tiene asignado.

```
public  class Conductor {
int IdConductor
string nombre
int IdAuto
Auto Auto
string usuario
string password
}
```

esto no me deja generar el archivo de migracion, claro, porque hay una relacion circular, si traigo el auto me trae el conductor, que a su vez tiene un auto que este tiene un conductor, etc.

Hay alguna forma, con anotations, hacer esta relacion y decirle que corte en la primera carga y no lo haga ciclica?
muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

este tipo de situaciones se pueden resolver de la siguiente forma. te aclaro que el ejemplo que te voy a mostrar es con un proyecto ASP de prueba pero al final es Entity Framework igual por lo que se puede aplicar perfectamente en tu caso.

para definir una relación de 1 a 1 con EF puedes definir en la clase Auto que su Id va a ser el mismo Id que el de Conductor, de esta forma has definindo un 1 a 1 ejemplo:

```
public class Conductor
{
    public int ConductorId { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string usuario { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

    public virtual Auto Auto { get; set; }
}



using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

 public class Auto
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Conductor")]
    public int ConductorId { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public virtual Conductor Conductor { get; set; }
}
```

con esta anotación estas declarando que el Id del Auto va a ser el mismo Id del Conductor, por lo que al llenar el campo ConductorId en tu formulario de Auto estas estableciendo al mismo tiempo su llave. despues de hacer una migración puedes ver en tu BD la tabla auto los campos que tiene y verás como se cumple todo lo expuesto. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Claro, si pensamos en el diseño, ese 1 a 1 lo podria haber dejado todo en la misma tabla, y listo, al hacerlo de este modo como planteas, comparten el id, ya que serian la "misma" entidad.
Esto lo quiero hacer en un proyecto que esta en producción, por las dudas no lo voy  a hacer como decís, en el próximo proyecto, ya a este tipo de relación lo voy a plantear compartiendo el id como planteas.
Muhcas gracias, muy buen aporte